# Control characters (carriage return, formatting? etc) removed when using html in attributedText in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a text coming from some wordpress editor which includes some text, formatting (carriage returns) and some basic html. When showing this in my iOS app i use

```
let attributedString = try! NSMutableAttributedString(data: myText.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
textview.attributedText = attributedString
```

This removes all the carriage returns from the text. If I just use

```
textview.text = myText
```

it will not show the html. Is it possible to show both html and this formatting? 
example, when entering this in the editor

```
"text text text

text text <a href="http://example.com">some link</a>

text text text"
```

and showing it in my app it will look like

> "text text text text text [some link](http://example.com) text text text"

I know this can be done by wrapping every paragraph in html p tags but I just want to be able to format the text using the enter key

Comment: `textview.text = myText`=> `textview.attributedText = attributedString`?

Comment: Yes that's what I tried, but that removes my carriage returns

Answer (score 0):

All whitespace character sequences, including newlines, in HTML are converted to a single space. That's a basic property of HTML.

If you need line breaks, use `<br>`. You can simply:

```
myText.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "<br>")
```

before converting to attributed string.

Answer (score 0):

> I know this can be done by wrapping every paragraph in html p tags but I just want to be able to format the text using the enter key

You need `<br>` to render hard returns, but you could add them programmatically if you want:

```
func html(from: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
    guard let data = from
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "<br>")
        .data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true) { else return nil }

    return try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType])
}
```

Then you can use this method like:

```
var myText = """
"text text text

text text <a href="http://example.com">some link</a>

text text text"
"""

if let html = html(from: myText) {
    // do something with html

}
```